# Clicking on checkbox changes input to css

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I have checkboxes on my list. When you click on any checkbox, the input that belongs to it get invisible. I used the following javascript function. but it didn't.

my js function:

```
function ActivePassive() {

    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("switchery");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (liste[i].checked) {
            console.log("aa"); // if checked = true, it write aa.
            document.getElementById("focus").style.display = 'block'; //but it doesn't work
            }
        else {
            console.log("bb"); // if checked = false, it write bb.
            document.getElementById("focus").style.display = 'none'; //but it doesn't work
            }
    }
}
```

mt html code:

```
        <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="checkbox checkbox-switchery">
                       <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].status, new {  @class = "switchery" , @onchange = "ActivePassive()" })
                  <label class="label-rounded bg-blue-300">
                      Yes/No
                        </label>
                    </label>
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </td>


 <td>
      <div id="focus" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model[i].Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                  </div>
            </div>
       </td>
```

Comment: *"but it didn't."*  didn't what?

Comment: Don't add code on comment section, add the information to your question, use the [edit]

Comment: in your function you have  if (liste[i].checked) { but your variable list you called list, liste[i] does not exist

Comment: This code `document.getElementById ("focus").` will always retrieve the same item. Assuming your code is within a loop, you should ensure your IDs are unique.

Comment: @Mary, If you have solved the issue, please write it as an answer and accept it. This will mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: I SOLVED** 
I caught the index value of the checkbox I selected. I found the index value I input next to the id I wrote. I did the same function I wrote in the script.
*I solved it like this*

```
function ActivePassive() {

    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("switchery");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (liste[i].checked) {

            document.getElementById("focus-i").style.display = 'block';  // here
            }
        else {
            document.getElementById("focus-i").style.display = 'none'; //here
            }
    }
}
```

```
 <div id="focus-@i" class="col-md-4"> *// get i value*
            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model[i].Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                  </div>
            </div>
       </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your code so that you can properly reference the item you want to toggle its display and build a reference to it from your checkbox. Yes, there are many ways to skin this cat but here's an attempt to help the OP with minimal refactoring.

Update your checkbox to include an attribute containing the index:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].status, new {  @class = "switchery" , @onchange = "ActivePassive(event)", data_chkbox_index = i })
```

Update your element ID to include the index, this ensures the ID is unique:

```
<div id="focus-@i">
```

Update your function to use the actual target checkbox (no need to loop through all) and update the display only on the particular element:

```
function ActivePassive(event) {
    //this is the actual clicked item
    var chkbox = event.target;
    //get the index from the checkbox
    var index = chkbox.getAttribute('data-chkbox-index');
    //determine what display value to set based off the checkbox
    var display = chkbox.checked? 'block' : 'none';

    //finally set the display value referencing the element ID with the index
    document.getElementById("focus-" + index).style.display = display;
}
```

HTH

Comment: " @data-chkbox-index  " is undefined.
is the name given here variable name?

Comment: and "event.target;" undefined